# Android Dialogbox For loop not executing?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, dialog

i want to move image from one folder to another , on alertDialogbox "yes" click event it should check if sourceImagePath is available in gridview's arraylist then it should be remove from arraylist then move to other folder.

code:

customDialog.java

```
    else if(option.equals("move")){

            builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>Move your File here?</font>"));
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener( ) {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    // just to take note of the location sources
                    Log.v("sourceLocation", "sourceLocation: " + source_path);
                    Log.v("sourceLocation", "targetLocation: " + all.current_path);

                    for (int i=0;i<PhotosActivity.al_folder_data.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(PhotosActivity.al_folder_data.get(i).equals(source_path)){
                            PhotosActivity.al_folder_data.remove(i);
                        }
                    }

                    move( );
                    if(move_copy_flag==true){
                        move_copy_flag=false;
                        activity.finish();
                    }

                }
            });
```

foor loop is not executing, it is skipping and come to the next line on move() method.

Comment: Because it is not matching this _if(PhotosActivity.al_folder_data.get(i).equals(source_path)){_

Comment: check PhotosActivity.al_folder_data.size is not zero and check if condition is true or not.

Comment: if condition is not executing , now i m checking for data in al_folder_data as u suggested...

Comment: it is showing "com.dkapps.galleryview.Model_images@c8dfc84"

Comment: as a single element in a al_folder_list data

Comment: thank you all it is solved, if condition is not matching data because i was calling arraylist, i should call a single image inside that arraylist. thanks!!!